# Problem while launching PMICP

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Followed the following tutorial https://libpointmatcher.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ICPIntro/
It works well till I open cloud_0.vtk and cloud_1.vtk in PARAVIEW and at the next step of launching pmicp with an empty ICP configuration I get an error, I tried to copy paste the file from the tutorial, In that case the error is following:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'PointMatcher<float>::ConvergenceError'         
  what():  ErrorMnimizer: no point to minimize                
Aborted (core dumped)
```

and when I launched the same YAML in the package provided in the package, the output is very unexpected:

```
* KDTreeMatcher: initialized with knn=1, epsilon=0, searchType=1 and maxDist=inf             
match ratio: 0.900055       
ICP transformation:            
   0.993545   -0.113204  0.00724467    0.608055              
   0.113237    0.993559 -0.00431907 -0.00381928            
-0.00670904   0.0051116    0.999964   0.0106469                           
          0           0           0           1
```

Please help how to correct this.
Ubuntu 15.10
Ros kinetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243477/problem-while-launching-pmicp/) by [The Gimmickk](https://answers.ros.org/users/27885/the-gimmickk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-09-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-26**:
In the future: please just answer your own question and then accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. That marks this question as answered and is much more visible from the question list than when you close it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please follow the following issue [here](https://github.com/ethz-asl/libpointmatcher/issues/172)

---

Originally posted by [The Gimmickk](https://answers.ros.org/users/27885/the-gimmickk/) with karma: 16 on 2016-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0